# Wordpress TinyMCE buttons

Tags: wordpress

For Wordpress TinyMCE when adding or editing posts.
I have this issue where I would like to have more buttons for user so it's same as admin. At the moment when you login as user it shows limited amount of buttons. Is there a way to show same buttons as admin for users aswell? See images below admin has more buttons... I can only get more buttons for superadmin user...

[image: Admin screen]

[image: User screen]

Comment: There are [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) for such tasks (can't remember the name now), where you can completely decide, which buttons to show to which user-group. Also this is a question for **wordpress.stackexchange.com**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure any user can toggle the visibility of all available buttons by selecting the icon before the TV called 'Kitchen Sink'. In your screen shots: Admin user has previously enabled it, other user hasn't.

You can force it to be always on with the following:

```
/**
 * Force the kitchen sink to always be on
 */
add_action('auth_redirect', 'tcb_force_kitch_sink_on');
function tcb_force_kitch_sink_on(){
  set_user_setting('hidetb', 1);
}
```

Comment: where would you include this function?

Comment: In your themes functions.php http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File or inside your plugin